# Styles player for Yamaha DGX 660

Tags: audio, keyboard, midi

I have a DGX 660 keyboard.
On this keyboard 200 styles files are preinstalled. But you can use 100 more...
2 ways exist: load them on the keyboard or use them on a USB key. The bank total can't exceed 300.

I found lot of styles on internet, thousands and thousands... I wanted to test them to keep the ones I like. If we use apps like Midi and Style Player or Stylemagic YA, I can't hear harmonic sounds to really evaluate them. The only way I found to hear the quality of a style file is to drop them 100 by 100 on a USB key and use them with the keyboard.

You can imagine the time needed to do this evaluation.
Someone have a solution for that ?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, Yamaha themselves never released a style editor to the public.
I haven't worked there for 20 years, but I don't think that has changed in the intervening period.

I used to, in the 90s, actually make these things for a living ;-)

I was part of Yamaha's writing & mixing/editing team who made the internal styles & a lot of the first release-cycle of the then-known 'disk styles' you could buy, initially for the high end products such as the PSR-6700, right up to the last before I left, the PSR-9000 & Tyros. Lower models would be handled by another team, who trimmed down, re-voiced & re-edited from the data we made for the top models.

So, my information is 20 years out of date, but these styles were always actually made in a static C Maj7 chord. The note function & movement was then re-calculated live during playback. Using C Maj7 as the base data gave each note a 'function' from which the ABC could be calculated. Root, 3, 5, & "flavour". There were some rather sophisticated algorithms & different rule-sets which dictated which note went to where on transposition, & these rules could be set per track/instrument by the programmer. Whether it was simple transposition of the entire chord - the simplest was to transpose in parallel, up until a certain key, then wrap over to transpose down [dumb but sometimes useful]. Much smarter algorithms could dictate quite clever re-voicing to make a player's voicings always appear to move to the nearest 'good' note for the chord, with correct voice-leading etc. Even more complex algorithms for other scale & non-scale notes were capable of keeping the whole thing sounding reasonably musical.

Unfortunately, the exact details of how this was done [because no other company had managed to achieve it] I have to keep to myself even to this day.

Anyway, the background aside, I still don't think there is a dedicated publicly-available Yamaha resource to handle these files at consumer-level. All 3rd party software will have had to try to reverse-engineer how the algorithms are applied.

The best resource I know of for this 3rd party software is curated by a chap called Jørgen Sørensen on his site - [The Unofficial YAMAHA Keyboard Resource Site](http://www.jososoft.dk/yamaha/index.htm) On two pages he has links to all the known editors for Yamaha keyboards - http://www.jososoft.dk/yamaha/software.htm [& see the header bar for 'Software 2'].

I haven't tested any of this myself, but I feel sure this is going to be your best resource.

Comment: Arranger keyboards were a valuable resource for me for learning music during the 80s, and I think a lot of music makers today would benefit from learning to play songs as chords and melody on an arranger keyboard. Do some Yamaha keyboards try to figure out the prevailing scale and key? Because that's often needed to make meaningful note choices. I remember the DSR-2000 model had a useful "I don't understand this chord" fallback where it would just play the lowest note as bass and all chord notes in a basic rhythm. Many modern keyboards fail to serve the user by trying to be too "intelligent".

Comment: I could tell you but then I'd have to shoot you ;-)) No, seriously, I can't say at all. It's very *sekrit* how it all works & appears to have some modicum of 'intelligence'. My knowledge is also going to be 20 years out of date.