# Do styles have expected sounds?

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions, styles

I was wondering if chord progressions and melody have to sound a certain way to be part of a style of music? Like Hard Rock or Goth. Never heard of goth but if I did I would expect it to have a creepy sound to it. I guess what I'm asking is do styles have expected sounds? When I play my keyboard I have styles on there that I wonder if there should be certain chords that should fit with the style... and also melody

Comment: Erm... _yes_? – I really don't see how this question could be answered. Please try focus it down a bit more what you're actually interested in.

Comment: Not everyone feels the same way, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: It would be good (for you) to listen to different styles. Maybe give you more insight than answers here.

Comment: Ref: https://music.stackexchange.com/a/99854/12556 We used to have a saying… "If you play heavy metal in Maj7 you get what you deserve."

Answer (score 1):

When people talk about "Styles" of music, they might be talking about various different things. Many styles are very associated with particular sounds; other times, musical styles might be also be associated with a type of dance, or a listening demographic, or a place, or a religion, or a period of history, or a style of performance or marketing, or a clothing fashion...

It is fair to say that *most* styles are associated with certain sounds:

- particular timbres
- particular chords and 'harmonic palettes'
- particular types of chord progression
- particular rhythms

...and so on.

In my opinion, 'Goth' or 'Gothic Rock' actually *isn't* overwhelmingly associated with expected sounds - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gothic_rock_artists contains a lot of bands who sound quite different from each other.

Comment: When I play my keyboard I have styles on there that I wonder if there should be certain chords that should fit with the style... and also melody.

Comment: @Leo35 interesting idea - though most home keyboards work by allowing the player to manually choose the chords and play the melody, so there would need to be another mode that would also generate chord progressions and melodies. "Algorithmic composition" and "generative music" are two similar ideas.